# can't change background color of polymer paper button

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

So I've got the following:

```
paper-button{
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
paper-button:hover{
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Anyway, the button text correctly displays as red, and when hovered the text correctly shows blue and the background correctly shows red, but when it's not hovered it's white, not blue. I've also tried:

```
 --paper-button-background: blue;
```

and

```
  background-color: blue;
```

with no success. the button is the following:

```
 <paper-button raised noink>raised</paper-button>
```

Why can't I style the `background-color`?

**UPDATE**

So as suggested when I add a class and select that class instead of selecting all paper-buttons it works, but it removes the text (or makes it the background color), but only when I add the class css code does it also remove the text from a paper-button without the class, which is even more confusing... When I remove the code that only selects the paper-buttons with the right class, then the paper-buttons without that class don't have the removed text bug.

Comment: use background instead of background-color.

Comment: in which browser you have tried? But your code works fine for me?

Comment: I've tried 'background' and 'background-color' as well as '--paper-button-background'

Comment: take a look of my code

Comment: When I copy and paste the code from [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-button) it works fine...

Comment: still u have the same prob?

Answer (score 0):

Change background-color to background.

```css
.paper-button{
  color: red;
  background: blue;
}
.paper-button:hover{
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="paper-button" value ="click">
```

Comment: So when I use button and not paper-button I don't get the material design of polymer, but it works. However, I added the class: paper-button and copied your css and it worked, so I guess it works only with the class, because I also tried your css in my 'paper-button' as opposed to '.paper-button'

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote. Don't have the reputation. I really hate the reputation system on this site...

Comment: I still don't understand why it only works if I add the class. I can stylize 3/4 of it without the class...

Comment: ok so now when I click on the button the text disappears (or turns blue?). I didn't have that problem before...

Comment: So when I add the css class code it also removes the text from the button without the class... but without the css class it works except for the background color when it's not hovered... Sorry for the comment spam but it's all important info.

Comment: which browser are you using? You have to check your css, may be there is something that you are missing.

Comment: Chrome (comment needs 15 characters)

Comment: Ok, and what are you doing buttons onclick?

Comment: I have no css or script on click currently

Answer (score 0):

You will create the css class and you can use this css
like this

```css
.paper-button{
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  padding:16px 32px;
}
.paper-button:hover{
  color: blue;
  background: red;
   padding:16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="paper-button" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it's a stupid answer but I found it. You have to embed the css in html like so:

```
 <style is="custom-style"> </style>
```

You can't have a separate style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

I don't know why you can't add the `is="custom style"` to the linked sheet, but that's the solution.

Answer (score -1):

```css
paper-button{
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  padding:16px 32px;
}
paper-button:hover{
  color: blue;
  background: red;
   padding:16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<paper-button raised noink>raised</paper-button>
```